# What does ...=... do in R?

Tags: r

What does `... = ...` mean as a function parameter?  I saw this in some R source code.  I understand that `...` is additional arguments, but not sure what the equals does?

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: sorry, this was used in a function call, not in the function definition.  PerformanceAnalytics:::SharpeRatio

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is superfluous and the same as `...`. Probably the author meant that the `...` of the called function should equal to the `...` of the calling function, but that's the same as using just `...` (in fact the `...=...` construct may be confusing since it may invoke the idea that arguments other than `...` of the called function won't be used which is not true).